# How to not show PDO errors Newbie

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

please be patient with me I am still learning, see attached code. this works perfectly for my application but now i want to take it live and in the odd occasion that there is an error i would like the user not to see a long string of SQL warning errors if that makes sense. is it possible to turn the error reporting off, or to show a simple message rather than the error codes.

I have compiled this from an online tutorial so im not 100% on what i should do, i have tried to delete the catch function but then it breaks the site.

```
try{

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email) VALUES (:email) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status='offline'";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    // Bind parameters to statement
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_SESSION['name']);


    // Execute the prepared statement
    $stmt->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e){
    die("ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: That's a very good question, though the answer is rather obvious: **just don't add** that die() statement! Then just configure PHP according to your needs: whether you want error to be shown or not. See my article on the [principles of error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting). Feel free to ask any questions if something is unclear.

Comment: thanks for your response. i actually tried that but then it seemed to break the website. ill double check my code again to make sure there isnt other mistakes causing this.